# Reloading cells in view after image downloaded

Tags: swift, xcode

I am currently learning swift. I have experience in android but now time for something new. I am starting with basics to load movie DB from `API` to table. I am storing dowloaded poster in Movie class (which also downloads them) when scrolling I can see the posters but after download the current cells in the view not updated, only after scroll. How can I implement `callback` from Movie to table view to update visible cells after download.

Movie:

```
import UIKit
let URL_PREFIX = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original"

class Movie {

let movieId: CLong?
let title: String?
let posterPath: String?
let overview: String?
let releaseDate: String?
var posterImage: UIImage?
var callback: ((_ id: Int) -> Void)?

init(movieId: CLong,title: String,posterPath: String,overview: String,releaseDate: String,posterImage: UIImage?=nil) {

    self.movieId = movieId
    self.title = title
    self.posterPath = posterPath
    self.overview = overview
    self.releaseDate = releaseDate
    self.posterImage = posterImage

    setResizedImage(path: posterPath)

}

func setResizedImage(path: String)
{
    let conPath = URL_PREFIX + path
    print("Path: \(conPath)")

    guard let urlPath = URL(string: conPath) else {
        print("You fucked up")
        return
    }


    print("Download Started")
    getData(from: urlPath) { data, response, error in
        guard let _ = data, error == nil else { return }
        print(response?.suggestedFilename ?? urlPath.lastPathComponent)
        print("Download Finished")

        //update

        DispatchQueue.main.async()
            {

              self.posterImage = UIImage(data: data!)

        }
    }
  }
}
```

MyViewController:

```
import UIKit
let URL_MOVIES = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/upcoming? 
api_key=000";

class DataViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate, 
UITableViewDataSource {
@IBOutlet weak var myTable: UITableView!
var movieArray :[Movie] = []

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return movieArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MovieTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as? CustomTableViewCell  else {
        fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of MovieTableViewCell.")
    }

    let movie = movieArray[indexPath.row]

    cell.title.text = movie.title
    cell.releaseDate.text = movie.releaseDate
    cell.overview.text = movie.overview

    //cell.url.text = movie.overview

    if (movie.posterImage==nil)
    {
        print("Loaded placeholder")
        cell.poster.image = UIImage(named: "poster")
    }
    else
    {
        print("Hello2")
         cell.poster.image = movie.posterImage
    }

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("You tapped cell number \(indexPath.row).")
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    myTable.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
    myTable.estimatedRowHeight = 50

    getJsonFromUrl()

}



func getJsonFromUrl(){
    let url = NSURL(string: URL_MOVIES)

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: (url as URL?)!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in

        if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary {

            if let resultArray = jsonObj.value(forKey: "results") as? NSArray
            {
                for film in resultArray
                {

                    if let movieDict = film as? NSDictionary
                    {

                        //getting the name from the dictionary
                        let id = movieDict.value(forKey: "id")
                        let title = movieDict.value(forKey: "title")
                        let posterPath = movieDict.value(forKey: "poster_path")
                        let overview = movieDict.value(forKey: "overview")
                        let releaseDate = movieDict.value(forKey: "release_date")


                        let movie = Movie(movieId:id as! CLong, title: title as! String, posterPath: posterPath as! String, overview: overview as! String, releaseDate: releaseDate as! String)

                        self.movieArray.append(movie)
                    }
                }
            }

            OperationQueue.main.addOperation({

                self.myTable.reloadData()
            })
        }
    }).resume()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the download function inside the cell custom class and assign the imageView inside the callback, but this has many problems such as redownloading same image multiple times when scrolling, it's better to use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage) or you can use [Kingfisher Library](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher)

```
import SDWebImage

cell.poster.sd_setImage(with: URL(string:movie.imageUrlStr), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))
```

Comment: Thank you for that. But I actually wish to learn how to implement the callback, or update data from movie class. Without using 3rd party.